# Retreiving a file from an Alternative Data Stream through "cat" command

Tags: powershell

I am hiding audio/video files in Alternate data streams (ADS) using the following command

`F:\>type "Message.mp3">"MainFile.txt:Message.mp3"`

While trying to retrieve the audio/video file back from ADS, or in other words, to suck file back out of an ADS and put it back in a regular file, I use "cat" command

`cat "f:\MainFile.txt:Message.mp3">"Message.mp3"`

The above command, when executed in Windows Powershell, retrieves the file but that file does not open or play successfully. Plus its size becomes almost double on retrieval.

Does anyone have a say on this?

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to hide a binary and you are using text commands. Please review the options for binary files in both the `type` and `Get-Content` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following two powershell commands will get the deed done.

```
$a = Get-Content f:\MainFile.txt:HANDS.3gp -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0
Set-Content f:\HANDS.3gp -Encoding Byte -Value $a
```

Comment: I get following error with above command: `Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Encoding'.
At line:1 char:31
+ $a = Get-Content test.txt:ato -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0; Set-Conten ...
+                               ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

Answer (score 2):

By default, `cat` (`Get-Content`) assumes the contents of the file are text, UTF-16LE specifically. Binary files like MP3s will get mangled when assumptions for text handling are applied to them.

The command processor's `type` preserves the bytes, so you can keep that part. To extract the file using PowerShell, you should be careful to work with bytes:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\full\path\to\output.mp3', (cat 'F:\MainFile.txt:Message.mp3' -Encoding Byte))
```

Comment: NThanks a lot for the kind reply. I had earlier got a solution by hit n trial. You r right, the Byte Encoding is the solution. Like to add ReadCount parameter to your command, as by default its value is 1 and it reads one byte at a time n so took much longer with media files, so when ReadCount is set to "0", it reads whole file at once.                                                       [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('F:\output.mp3', (cat 'F:\MainFile.txt:Message.mp3' -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0))

Comment: I get this error when run above command on Win 10: `Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Encoding'.
At line:1 char:59
+ ... ile]::WriteAllBytes('july2.pdf', (cat 'test.txt:ato' -Encoding Byte))
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

Comment: @Zimba Ah, make sure to qualify the path name, e.g. by specifying the full path or prepending the name with ``.\`` for a file in the current directory. If the name isn't qualified, PowerShell will not recognize it as an item in the file system provider and will not add the `-Encoding` dynamic parameter.